# ClassNotFoundError ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am getting a NoClassError and i do not know what is causing it. I'm new to java. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: arrayList/ArrayListStrings
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: arrayList.ArrayListStrings
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

      package arrayList;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class ArrayListStrings {
        public static void main(String[]args){
        ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();

        stringList.add("94043");
        stringList.add("95043");
        stringList.add("96043");
        stringList.add("94043");

        stringList.set(0,"98043");

        for (String value : stringList){
            System.out.println(value);
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you compiling and executing?

Comment: You're probably not running it correctly, but it's impossible to say, since you don't include what causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasting the code and running it on an IDE produces no errors, so it might be how you are calling the main method in your class.

While packages and folders are the same in java, declaring a package creates a logic tree from where the classes are hierarchically accessed. So run in a terminal from where the package (directory) arrayList is stored: 
`java arrayList.ArrayListStrings`

Or if you want to run from the directory where the .class is stored, change the classpath (path where java can locate classes) manually by using the -classpath (or -cp) option: 
`java -classpath .. arrayList.ArrayListStrings`

Answer (score 0):

Run the program by specifying fully classified name. It works!
**java arrayList.ArrayListStrings**

With out specifying package name, if you run it, it will throw **NoClassDefFoundError**.